# Multiple Regression in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, regression, linear-regression, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to build a multiple regression model in Snowflake following the structure referenced in this blog post (http://sqldatamine.blogspot.com/2013/12/true-multiple-regression-using-sql.html), but I'm struggling to adapt this to Snowflake SQL structure particularly with stored procedures in Javascript.

Here is the section of the blog post I'm trying to replicate:

```
declare @p int
set @p = 1

while @p <= (select max(xn) from #x)
 begin  
  insert into #c
  select  xn cxn,  zn czn, sum(xv*zv)/sum(zv*zv) cv 
   from #x join  #z on  xid = zid where zn = @p-1 and xn>zn group by xn, zn
  insert into #z
  select zid, xn,xv- sum(cv*zv) 
   from #x join #z on xid = zid   join  #c  on  czn = zn and cxn = xn  where xn = @p and zn<xn  group by zid, xn,xv
  set @p = @p +1

 end
```

And here is my attempt:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TEST_TABLE (ID int, AREA float, ROOMS float, ODD float, PRICE float);
    INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE SELECT 1, 2202, 3, 1, 400;
    INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE SELECT 2, 1600, 3, 0, 330;
    INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE SELECT 3, 2400, 3, 1, 369;
    INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE SELECT 4, 1416, 2, 1, 232;
    INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE SELECT 5, 3000, 4, 0, 540;

--INDEPENDENT VARIABLE VECTOR--
CREATE TEMP TABLE X_VAR AS
  SELECT ID xid, 0 xn, 1 xv FROM TEST_TABLE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, 1, ROOMS FROM TEST_TABLE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, 2, AREA FROM TEST_TABLE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, 3, ODD FROM TEST_TABLE;

--DEPENDANT VARIABLE VECTOR--
CREATE TEMP TABLE Y_VAR AS
  SELECT ID yid, 0 yn, PRICE yv FROM TEST_TABLE;

--ORTHOGONAL PROCESSED VALUES--
CREATE TEMP TABLE Z_VAR (zid int, zn int, zv float);
    INSERT INTO Z_VAR SELECT ID, 0 zn, 1 zv FROM TEST_TABLE;

--ORTHOGONALIZATION COEFFICIENTS--
CREATE TEMP TABLE C_VAR (cxn int, czn int, cv float);
    INSERT INTO C_VAR SELECT ID, 0 zn, 1 zv from TEST_TABLE;

--REGRESSION COEFFICIENTS--
CREATE TEMP TABLE B_VAR (bn int, bv float);

--FIRST LOOP: ORTHOGONALIZATION COEFFICIENT CALC--
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ORTH()
    RETURNS FLOAT NOT NULL
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
  $$
        var sql_counter =
            `SELECT MAX(XN) FROM X_VAR`;
        var sql_bulk =
            `INSERT INTO C_VAR
                    SELECT XN CXN, ZN CZN, SUM(XV*ZV)/SUM(ZV*ZV) CV
                        FROM X_VAR
                    JOIN Z_VAR ON XID = ZID
                        WHERE ZN = p-1
                        AND XN > ZN
                        GROUP BY XN, ZN
                    INSERT INTO Z_VAR
                    SELECT ZID, XN, XV-SUM(CV*ZV)
                        FROM X_VAR
                    JOIN Z_VAR ON XID = ZID
                    JOIN C_VAR ON CZN = ZN AND CXN = XN
                        WHERE
                        1=1
                        AND XN = P
                        AND ZN < XN
                    GROUP BY ZID, XN, XV`;
        var p = 1;
        while (p <= snowflake.execute(sql_counter)) {
            snowflake.execute ({sqlText: sql_bulk})
            p = p + 1
            }
    $$
;

CALL ORTH();
SELECT * FROM C_VAR;
```

I keep running into an empty argument error at the snowflake.execute line. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This runs, but I'm not sure what it's trying to do. The problem is in your line here:

```
while (p <= snowflake.execute(sql_counter)) {
```

The problem is the query isn't being executed properly. You have to send it a statement object, which is the {sqlText: sql_bulk} you have on the next line.

```
--FIRST LOOP: ORTHOGONALIZATION COEFFICIENT CALC--
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ORTH()
    RETURNS FLOAT NOT NULL
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
  $$
        var sql_counter =
            `SELECT MAX(XN) as C FROM X_VAR`;
        var sql_bulk =
            `INSERT INTO C_VAR
                    SELECT XN CXN, ZN CZN, SUM(XV*ZV)/SUM(ZV*ZV) CV
                        FROM X_VAR
                    JOIN Z_VAR ON XID = ZID
                        WHERE ZN = p-1
                        AND XN > ZN
                        GROUP BY XN, ZN
                    INSERT INTO Z_VAR
                    SELECT ZID, XN, XV-SUM(CV*ZV)
                        FROM X_VAR
                    JOIN Z_VAR ON XID = ZID
                    JOIN C_VAR ON CZN = ZN AND CXN = XN
                        WHERE
                        1=1
                        AND XN = P
                        AND ZN < XN
                    GROUP BY ZID, XN, XV`;
        var p = 1;
        while (p <= ExecuteSingleValueQuery('C', sql_counter)) {
            snowflake.execute ({sqlText: sql_bulk})
            p = p + 1
            }

// Added a helper function

function ExecuteSingleValueQuery(columnName, queryString) {
    var out;
    cmd1 = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs;

    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue(columnName);
$$
;

CALL ORTH();
SELECT * FROM C_VAR;

SELECT MAX(XN) FROM X_VAR
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Greg. Honestly I'm not 100% sure what each block of code is doing. I'm trying to build a multiple regression model exclusively within SQL, and I'm adapting the code in the blog post so that I can deconstruct it and possible rebuild it with a use case.

The gist of the post is that SQL is built in such a way that allows for matrix multiplication in order to solve multiple regression models. I think these tables are manipulating the data in such a way to prime them for multiplication.